# Can't get fields to show in Drupal Views module

Tags: drupal, module, view, drupal-views

I have a view setup in the Views module that outputs an RSS feed of nodes. In the Fields section I have specified that I want the Title, Date and Body in the feed, but Views seems to ignore all but the title (and the link which I haven't specified to include). I know it's using the Views module because if I remove the title for each item or rename the entire feed it is reflected in the actual feed. I don't think there's any tpl files that are restricting the output either, but I don't know all the places to look. Does this sound familiar?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" >
  <channel>
<title>RSS Feed Title</title>
<description>...</description>
<link>http://...</link>
<item>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link>http://...</link>
</item>
<item>
  <title>Title</title>
  <link>http://...</link>
</item>
.
.
.
```

Comment: I think you need to give us a bit more information on what's going on.  Perhaps a screenshot of the views config page?

Comment: Added the image and example of whats in the feed

Comment: A screenshot of the tab for the Feed display specifically may be more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the **Feed** display tab. Under **Basic settings**, click on the gear icon for th **Row style**. Check the **Display type** and set it to something other than *Title only*.

You may also want to check out the [Views RSS module](https://drupal.org/project/views_rss). It provides more flexibility in terms of what you're able to include in the feed. It's especially useful for including CCK fields in the feed.

Comment: This led me in the right direction. I think I had the Feed > Basic Settings > Style all messed up. Resetting Style to "RSS Feed" and Row Style to "Node" gave a pretty full featured feed. I ended up using Style = "RSS Feed - Fields" (great name) I was able to specify the exaclt fields I wanted. Thanks!